# Possible to chain queries in Rails 3?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord

I have something like the following

```
class Group < ActiveRecord::Base
has_many :group_users
end

class GroupUser < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user, :group
end

class User < ActiveRecord::Base
has_many :group_users
end
```

The reason I'm not using has_many_through is because the group_user class has more information than just a link table, so I want to be able to access those values.

What I would like to do though is pass @groups to the page and loop through the group users but get at the user object as well

so

```
<% @groups.each do |group| %>
    <%= group.group_user.user.name %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: Just a quick note, I think you may be confusing `has_many :through` with `has_and_belongs_to_many`.  HMT allows for other columns in the join table.

Comment: Well, my second code sample is a little bit misleading, I'm actually on the show page, so I'm really passing the @group object, so I would really like to loop through the @group.group_users if that's possible

Comment: @Brian - maybe I should read through that again, I'm still a little confused by this section of ActiveRecord.  Do you have anything you recommend that walks through it?

Comment: A bit old, but this will help:  http://railscasts.com/episodes/47-two-many-to-many

Comment: Q: should the law of Demeter be applicable in this situation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is how I would do it:

**User Model**

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :memberships
  has_many :groups, :through => :memberships
end
```

**Group Model**

```
class Group < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :memberships
  has_many :users, :through => :memberships
end
```

**Membership Model**

```
class Membership < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :group
end
```

**Controller**

```
def show
  @groups = Group.all
end
```

**View**

```
<% @groups.each do |group| %>
  <% group.users.each do |user| %>
    <%= user.name %> 
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

There are probably a few ways to do it, but this should get you started.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

If you want to access attributes from the GroupUser model, just do this:

```
<% @groups.each do |group| %>

   <% group.group_users.each do |group_user| %>
     <%= group_user.attribute_name %> 
     <%= group_user.user.name
  <% end %> 
<% end %>
```

To make this more efficient from the SQL side of things you can use eager loading:

```
Group.all(:includes => [:group_users => :user])
```

F